# Android Fingerprints: hasEnrolledFingerprints triggers exception on some Samsungs

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I'm seeing a lot of exceptions in our production app when enabling fingerprints coming from Android 6 users, which I cannot reproduce on any of my local Samsung devices. The stacktrace is:

```
Message: SecurityException: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=24365, uid=10229 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
android.os.Parcel.readException in Parcel.java::1620
android.os.Parcel.readException in Parcel.java::1573
android.hardware.fingerprint.IFingerprintService$Stub$Proxy.hasEnrolledFingerprints in IFingerprintService.java::503
android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints in FingerprintManager.java::762
android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23.a in SourceFile::39
android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompat$Api23FingerprintManagerCompatImpl.a in SourceFile::239
android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompat.a in SourceFile::66
```

This is just using the standard `FingerprintManagerCompat` class from the support library, and the check works correctly on other devices.

I don't want to add this permission to my app - it seems to have nothing to do with fingerprints.

Has anyone encountered anything like  this?

Comment: In order to reproduce this issue you need to have fingerprints registered but no screen lock: swipe or none. Otherwise, there is no problem. Either way, is there any solution for this case?

Comment: @Petrakeas for the scenario of fingerprints enabled but no lock screen, I already have a check for `KeyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()`

Comment: In my S7 the problem was only reproduced in the case that `isKeyguardSecure()` returned false. Calling the 2 methods in @David Medenjak's answer solves the problem even in this case.

Comment: @Petrakeas I needed to do one extra thing to reproduce this issue. So first you need to have fingerprints registered and screen lock set to swipe or none. Then I had to restart the device. After that I was able to reproduce this issue constantly. And as you mentioned the answer of David Medenjak solves this problem.

Comment: @Wirling On my Huawei device, if I set my screen lock set to Swipe or None, then it deletes all the registered Fingerprints.

Answer (score 23):

I came across the same problem on a Samsung Galaxy S6, running Android 6.0.1

The Problem was caused by calling

```
fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()
```

I fixed it by adding a call to check for hardware before:

```
fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()
    && mFingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()
```

Checking for fingerprints without the hardware available seems to cause this exception on some devices.

Comment: I do this exactly and still have the issue.  I added this information to my question.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @kos On which devices do you see the issue?

Comment: I also get same error. And I checked my code, I've just added hardwareControl before call hasEnrolledFingerprints(). Do you have another idea?

Comment: @atasoyh No, I'm sorry. This fixed the issue for me back in the day. I didn't do any more tests

Comment: This code works for me, Samsung J1 Mini 6.0.1. I've check first if `isHardwareDetected()` before calling `hasEnrolledFingerprints()`

Comment: Works for me. Caught this issue on Samsung J5 and Samsung A3

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening after you upgrade your Phone OS , Go to developer options --> Verify apps over USB --> Switch it off , learned it the hard way , hope it helps some valuable time !
[image]